# Инкремент C++

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    y = x + (x++);

    cout << "y=" << y << endl << "x=" << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Почему `y` равен трем, а не двум?

Comment: Хотя нет, я не правильно понял :)

Comment: Если написать так:
y = 1 + (x++);
То 'y' будет равен двум.

Comment: Компилятор Mingw.

Comment: А вообще компилятор выдает предупреждение:
operation on 'x' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инкремент оставляет после себя копию объекта, каким он был до изменения.

Поскольку первым выполняется выражение в скобках (x++), то оно заменятся аналогичной копией (1), а сам x увеличивается до 2. Следующим шагом идет сложение копии с самим значением x, которое к этому времени уже увеличилось. Вот и получается y = 2 + (1);

---

А вообще тут все зависит метода вычисления компилятором значений и если он будет другим, то выражение будет равно двум. Если стандарт накладывает требования на такой порядок(а мне лень лезть в стандарт), то все нормально, иначе undefined behavior.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex Krass опередил :)

Answer (score 0):

И кстати так не только в си http://ideone.com/yPa7iw